# what does this symbol mean in the typescript '< >'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am a beginner in Typescript and JavaScript trying to understand a code. I encounter "< >" at several places in the code, as described in an example below.

```
(value: any, manager: ManagerBase<any>|undefined)
```

Why we use "< >" in typescript.

Thanks

Comment: You're learning from some book or guide right? That's fairly basic syntax and I'm sure it will be explained.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManagerBase` is a generic type. It uses a parameter for a type in its definition (not present in the code you posted).

Let's say we have the type `Sample<T>` defined like this:

```js
type Sample<T> = T[];
```

This makes `Sample<T>` an alias of the type "array of values of type `T`". The type `Sample<number>` is the same as `number[]`, `Sample<string>` is the same as `string[]` and so on. `Sample<any>` is the same as `any[]`.

In the code you posted, the type `ManagerBase<any>` uses `any` as the value of `T`.

Read about ["generics"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the TypeScript handbook.

Answer (score 0):

This symbol is used to specify the type when using generics.
See the official TypeScript-Documentation for further information: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html